# How to show epoch time from caffe log file?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

During the training, I write the log output to file by using the bellow script

```
~/caffe/build/tools/caffe train --solver=solver.prototxt -gpu 0 2>&1 | tee -a my_log.log
```

To extract it, I used the python script:

```
python ~/caffe/tools/extra/parse_log.py ./my_model.log .
```

The output as

```
NumIters,Seconds,LearningRate,loss
0.0,2.538275,0.002,1.38629
20.0,56.872385,0.002,1.1333
40.0,106.103729,0.002,0.245525
60.0,144.78454,0.002,0.31936
80.0,168.363851,0.002,0.160776
100.0,191.590772,0.002,1.06693
120.0,215.290937,0.002,0.549629
140.0,238.70139,0.002,0.139573
160.0,262.053791,0.002,0.328959
180.0,286.324327,0.002,0.326179
```

With batch_size is 4. How can I draw the training loss graph with x-axis is epcho and the y-axis is the loss? I only can draw a graph with the x-axis is iteration and y-axis are loss.

Answer (score 0):

epoch_no = iteration_no*size_of_iteration/total_number_of_samples,
where:
iteration_no - first column in your report,
size_of_iteration is defined in your prototxt file (batch_size parameter of your data level, if you use ordinary data level), 
total_number_of_samples is known from your database with samples.